# My class isn't defined in the scope?

Tags: c++

I'm just starting to learn C++ as an already-experienced programmer in several other languages. The issue I'm having is probably a very obvious error on my end.

I have a class called Test in its own file, and it also has the respective header file. However, when I try to create an instance of it in main, I get this error:

```
Error: Test was not declared in this scope.  
Error: Expected ';' before 'to'
```

This is my main:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Test to;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the Header for Test:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H


class Test
{
    public:
        Test();
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

This is the Test Class:

```
#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Test::Test()
{

}
```

As you can see it is a simple class with an empty constructor. I have no idea what I could possibly be doing wrong here, so any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Thanks for the help, I knew it would be something stupidly obvious :P

Comment: You forgot to `#include "Test.h"` in the source that's giving you that error.

Comment: Why the offtopic close votes? Looks like programming to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include "Test.h"
```

in your main file also.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the header containing the `Test` class so the `main` can "see" it. Try this code instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"

int main()
{
    Test to;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the question, 'Test.cpp' is including 'Test.h' - not super important, but I'm pretty sure the header isn't named "Test.hpp"

Comment: @E.Moffat you're right, just force of habit to name all my headers *.hpp. Editing the response now.